# $(document).ready() doesn't seem to work on Internet Explorer. How can I fix this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, debugging

Our website seems to work well with Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox and Safari but I noticed that it doesn't work properly on Internet Explorer. More specifically, it doesn't invoke the `$(document).ready(function ());` on Internet Explorer for specific types of pages. I don't have access to Internet Explorer with me nor can I debug my localhost code on it but I'd highly appreciate if someone could tell me what's wrong in my code. I can't seem to find anything wrong with it (unless jquery doesn't always work in IE).

For example, check out the following link: http://www.listicle.co/list/user/post.php?listid=589

All of the code works in all other browsers except IE. Can someone with access to IE and IE debugger tools pinpoint what I can change to fix this? I'm really pulling hairs here trying to understand why this isn't working. I tried debugging on a friend's computer and all I could infer is that the document ready code is never invoked.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to use jQuery-1.X in IE<9, older IEs are not supported in jQuery-2.X.

Comment: You have a bunch of HTML errors in that page including scripts after `</body>`, `<div>` tags in your `<head>` section, unmatched tags, etc...  I'd suggest you first validate your page and make it all legal HTML as this is often a cause of browser differences/problems.

Comment: @Teemu, excellent troubleshooting! You should make this an answer.

Comment: Hmm. I tried to test in the new IE as well but it was failing there too.

Comment: @MacNoob jfriend00's list is endless, IE is not good at parsing invalid HTML. Please fix the issues with HTML, then try again.

Comment: @Teemu hahaha okay. I understand that W3C validator reports a lot of issues but we're also using Bootstrap which has issues of it's own. Is there anyway I can find out what exactly is the weird part?

Comment: @MacNoob Well, `div`s in the `head` and `script`s after `</body>` are really weird ; ). At minimum you need to close your tags properly...

Comment: Haha. Well I changed that and fixing more problems as well. Here, take a look at W3C validator results now (fixed 50 errors at least): http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.listicle.co%2Flist%2Fuser%2Fpost.php%3Flistid%3D590&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=1

Comment: BTW @Teemu which jQuery version should I use? What do you recommend? A link would be really helpful if you have it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It can fail in IE if there *any* error in the page. Check out the developer console in IE and fix all the errors.

For example, I once had an error

> SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'autocomplete'

on the page and then none of the code in

```
$(document).ready(function ())
```

was executed.

When I fixed the error, it started working.

Answer (score -1):

jQuery document ready works with IE, however IE does have some poor support for JavaScript, so there could be other issues which prevented the code from running correctly in IE.

One place for instance, where I sometimes  forgotten is array/object literal in IE must not end with a comma. Other browsers would happily accept the extra comma, but IE will throw (silent) syntax error.

Comment: This sounds like a comment, not an answer to their specific problem.